# Is there a simple way to delete a file from a shared network drive, which is in use by other users?

Tags: networking, network-drive, locked-files

At my workplace, I have taken over maintainance and development responsibilities of  a C# windows desktop application. The application is compiled into a .exe-file, placed in a shared network drive, and linked to from our intranet page.

When deploying new versions of the application, the standard procedure has been to delete the old file, and simply replace it with the new one. However, the number of users are increasing, and it is becoming hard to find a time of day where no users has the application open.

I have researched a bit on how to force deletion, even if the file is in use, but all of the solutions revolves around a single computer / single user setup.

Solutions containing rebooting with Linux CD or whatever is not going to work for me, as it would simply be easier to upload new versions of the system with version numbers in the file name, and change the link path every time.

(We are also considering remaking the whole application from a desktop app, to a webapp)

Are there any easy ways to force deletion of a shared network drive file, which is in use by one or more users?

Answer (score 0):

Found this on searching on google: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/force-windows-delete-file/

native command on windows:

```
del /f file
```

or another program

Another solution could be to close all the users' connections to the machine hosting the executable file, then change the file. The file should not be used anymore.

Comment: Translated from my language settings: "The Process can not access the file, because it is used by another process" In other words, this does not work.

Comment: I updated my answer, did you try the last solution?

Comment: That is not an option, unfortunately. The drive contains a great number of company shared files, and I am not the admin of it.

Comment: Found this thing: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783450%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
Every access on a shared resource should create a network descriptor, which can technically be closed.
Another discussion is running here on what seems to be the same topic: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/13779c78-0c73-4477-8014-f2eb10f3f10f/how-to-see-users-file-access-list-of-shared-folders-and-files-on-server-2008-r2?forum=winservergen

Comment: This looks promising, but I have to go a little in depth with it before I understand it :). Thanks